# Automapper Convention

Tags: c#, automapper

Is is possible with [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to setup a convention so that maps do not have to be created by hand for situations where the entity you are mapping to just has say "ViewModel" appended.

As an example I would rather not have to setup the following map:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Error, ErrorViewModel>();
```

I understand if projection is required that I would need to create a custom map, but having a convention to create maps would be nice.

Comment: As a side note, we've gone back and forth on adding basically scanning.  Even with a large # of mapping definitions (around 4-500), it just wasn't enough of a pain for us to really take a look at it.

Comment: try the ValueInjecter http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/documentation, it doesn't require creation of maps for each combination of type to type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use `Mapper.DynamicMap<TDest>(source)` to map.

As you can see in the example below, it automatically maps the matching properties from source to destination.

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = new Foo {Value = "Abc"};
        var destination = Mapper.DynamicMap<FooViewModel>(source);

        Debug.Assert(source.Value == destination.Value);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen Mapper.DynamicMap