# How to map from base type of object?

Tags: automapper

I have two types:

```
class Source {
  public object Data { get; set; }
}

class Destination {
  public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

that I want to map between where in both `Source` and `Destination` the property `Data` is some type for which there exists a mapping. For example.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceData1, DestinationData1>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceData2, DestinationData2>();
```

Currently my mapping file looks like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceData1, DestinationData1>();
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceData2, DestinationData2>();

// This is the bit that looks bad to me:
Mapper
   .CreateMap<object, object>()
   .Include<SourceData1, DestinationData1>()
   .Include<SourceData2, DestinationData2>()
```

Needing to include all allowed maps from object seems a bit clunky and likely to get really annoying once the solution grows a bit. If I don't include them then `Map` fails to correctly map these types.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: It depends - are the mappings based on convention, e.g. will it always be `SourceData1` maps to `DestinationData1` - what actual type names will be involved? I'd suggest something along the lines of a convention based mapping solution that will auto register types from an assembly based on naming

Comment: Alternatively - could `DynamicMap` work for you since if you are trying to just auto-register you aren't worried about data-shaping... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030227/automapper-convention

Comment: @Charleh - yes in this instance it is safe to assume that the only mapping from `SourceData1` will be to `DestinationData1` in the application.

Comment: I'd go down the `DynamicMap` route - you can just call `DynamicMap` whenever you want with the two types you want to map and AutoMapper will map the matching properties. As far as I know the first time you call it for a pair of types it will do it's usual map wizardry in the background which should make subsequent calls as quick as a standard `Map()` call. It also detects if a map has already been set up for two types and uses the existing configuration (to clarify: this is a **configuration free** mapping method - but it will use a pre-existing config if one is present)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that the behaviour I wanted from the mapper was for it to inject `Source.Data` onto `Destination.Data` based on the runtime type of `Source.Data`. Specifically, for a given type `TSource` I wanted to be able to define exactly one destination type `TDestination` such that when `Source.Data` has type `TSource` then `Destination.Data` has type `TDestination`.

The problem with `Map` or `DynamicMap` is that you must know the destination type when you perform the mapping, but at configuration time all you know about the type of `Destination.Data` is that it is `object` - you need to explicitly state the type destination type and the only way you can do that is by maintaining a mapping of source type to target type.

I've implemented a couple of extension methods on the `AutoMapper` configuration methods that allow a `Map` be registered for injection and for a `Member` to be resolved using the injection strategy:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

using AutoMapper;

/// <summary>
/// The <seealso cref="AutoMapper"/> extensions.
/// </summary>
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The injection maps.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly SortedDictionary<Type, Type> Injections = 
        new SortedDictionary<Type, Type>(new TypeComparer());

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers a mapping expression for injection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">
    /// The expression to register fo injection.
    /// </param>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">
    /// The source type.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TDestination">
    /// The destination type.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <returns>
    /// The original <see cref="IMappingExpression"/> to allow for fluent chaining.
    /// </returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
    /// Thrown when <typeparam name="TSource"/> is an interface or has already been enabled.
    /// </exception>
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> RegisterForInjection<TSource, TDestination>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
        where TSource : class
        where TDestination : class // These constraints mean that null can be mapped to null.
    {
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);

        // Interfaces do not have a strict hierarchy so the cannot be registered.
        if (sourceType.IsInterface)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format(
                "The type {0} is an interface and interface types cannot be registered for injection", 
                sourceType));
        }

        // This is important: for injection to work there can be exactly one target.
        if (Injections.ContainsKey(sourceType))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                string.Format("The type {0} has already been registered for injection", sourceType));
        }

        Injections.Add(sourceType, typeof(TDestination));

        return expression;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instructs the mapper to resolve the destination member using an injection 
    /// strategy based on the actual type of the source member at runtime.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="expression">
    /// The member expression on which to use an injection strategy.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="sourceMember">
    /// The source member to map from.
    /// </param>
    /// <typeparam name="TSource">
    /// The source type.
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TMember">
    /// The source member type (probably object).
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">
    /// When the actual type of <typeparam name="TMember"/> has not been registered for injection.
    /// </exception>
    public static void InjectFrom<TSource, TMember>(
        this IMemberConfigurationExpression<TSource> expression,
        Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> sourceMember)
        where TMember : class
    {
        var getSourceMember = sourceMember.Compile();

        expression.ResolveUsing(
            s =>
            {
                var sourceMemberValue = getSourceMember(s);
                if (sourceMemberValue == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var sourceMemberType = sourceMemberValue.GetType();

                Type destinationMemberType = null;

                // Because the injections are sorted by number of super classes it is 
                // guaranteed that the first one that is assignable from the source type
                // is the most derived.
                foreach (var injection in Injections)
                {
                    if (injection.Key.IsAssignableFrom(sourceMemberType))
                    {
                        // {injection.Key} value = default({sourceMemberType}) compiles.
                        destinationMemberType = injection.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (destinationMemberType == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(
                        string.Format(
                        "The type {0} has not been enabled for injection.", 
                        sourceMemberType));
                }

                return Mapper.Map(sourceMemberValue, sourceMemberType, destinationMemberType);
            });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type comparer.
    /// </summary>
    private class TypeComparer : IComparer<Type>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compares <paramref name="x"/> with <paramref name="y"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">
        /// The left hand type.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="y">
        /// The right hand type
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The difference in the number of super classes between y and x, specifically: 
        /// x &lt; y if x has more super classes than y
        /// </returns>
        public int Compare(Type x, Type y)
        {
            return CountSuperClasses(y) - CountSuperClasses(x);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Counts the number of super classes beneath <paramref name="type"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">
        /// The type.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The number of super classes beneath <paramref name="type"/>.
        /// </returns>
        private static int CountSuperClasses(Type type)
        {
            var count = 0;
            while (type.BaseType != null)
            {
                ++count;
                type = type.BaseType;
            }

            return count;
        }
    }
}
```